# Does the position of a comment in a CompoundExpression matter for the result obtained with Out (%)?

Tags: evaluation, output, comment

I would like to understand what happens when we include a comment at the end of a line that ends with a semicolon.

For example, if you execute

```
x;
%/.{x->1} (*some comment*);
%
```

you obtain `1`. However, the following code:

```
x;
%/.{x->1};(*some comment*)
%
```

ignores the rule and the output is `x`.

The point is that if I remove the comment `(*some comment*)` from any of these two cases, the result is correct. So, what is the role of the position of the comment in all of this?

I do not know if it is a bug in my version (11.0) or if I have misunderstood something (related with the real meaning of ";" as a composition of expressions, or with the correct use of comments).

Comment: I just reworded the title to make your question more easily found and read. Roll back, if you do not like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble comes from the number of input lines used: If I copy your second example it just takes two lines - not three.

Note the difference:

```
1;
2;
%
```

> 2

```
1;
2; %
```

> 1

You will get a `1` in both of your examples if you press `Return` before the last `%`. `%` really is [`Out[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html?q=Out) and will reference the previous *line of input*.

**Edit**

One should note that `Out` references to the result of a `CompoundExpression` (cf. the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html)).

```
In[1]:= CompoundExpression[2^2,Null] (* 2^2; *)
In[2]:= %
```

> Out[2]= 4

But the behavior of `Out` is different for other expressions:

```
In[3]:= Null
In[4]:= %
```

> (* No output will be shown, e.g. Out[4]= Null *)

*The In- and Out-numbers here are simply exemplary.*

Comment: Yes, totally right! Indeed, taking the second example but without the semicolon, if you click in between the input and the comment and write `;`, a little space appears after the semicolon. And it seems that the line break before the third line has been eliminated. But it is a bit confusing that the number of input lines you see do not coincide with the real one.

Comment: @A.JimenezCano I think it is worth to write a bug report to the tech support on this.